# MySQL Query problem in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

So I'm using the following:

```
    $r = new Record();
    $r->select('ip, count(*) as ipcount');
    $r->group_by('ip');
    $r->order_by('ipcount', 'desc');
    $r->limit(5);

    $r->get();

    foreach($r->all as $record)
    {
        echo($record->ip." ");
        echo($record->ipcount." <br />");
    }
```

Standard:

```
SELECT `ip`, count(*) as ipcount FROM (`soapi`) GROUP BY `ip` ORDER BY `ipcount` desc LIMIT 5;
```

And I only get the last (fifth) record echo'ed out and *no* `ipcount` echoed.

Is there a different way to go around this? I'm working on learning DataMapper (hence the questions) and need to figure some of this out. I haven't quite wrapped my head around the whole ORM thing.

Is there a way to set the `count(*) as ipcount` without the funny `select()` statement? I don't think it's triggering for some reason. This could also be a bug in DataMapper, but I'm less certain of that.

Also I found that even if I use the `$r->query()` method it doesn't return anything except the last entry if I use something like `SELECT`ip`FROM`soapi`WHERE 1;`. It will however return everything (like it should) if I say `SELECT * FROM soapi WHERE 1;`. If it doesn't have the `*` it only returns the last line.

Just verified with the new query, anything except selecting all columns (`*`) only returns the last record. Any help with this would be great. You can craft a statement like `select *, count(*) as ipcount` but then you still don't have access to it via `$record->ipcount`.

Comment: how do you know thats its the fifth record? Can you please post your query in the standard SQL format?

Comment: Added the standard format, and I know it's the fifth because if I run the standard query through the output is the same as the last entry on the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, once you use COUNT() function in MySQL, it will only return 1 value. Hence you `ip` result data would not display out.

I suggest you just split this 2 queries. 
1. for COUNT(*)
2. for `ip`

Hope this help.